# Cannot make http GET request on localhost of the android device/emulator

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I have made test application to investigate the issue related to http request. It is an android application where I'm making request to localhost:

```java
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("http://127.0.0.1")
        .build();

try {
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    Log.v("krv", response.toString());

} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.v("krv", e.toString());
}
```

As result on device emulator I have *"java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /127.0.0.1:80"* exception. With any other request on an external resource(like google.com) all are Ok. Also I have installed IIS. Operating system is Windows 10.

P.S. Really what I need - to be able to make http request on stb device where http server is run(where I have the same problem). I guess both issues have similar reason. Could you give me any advice how to fix/debug my problem...

Comment: So your server is running on the emulator too? As localhost/127.0.0.1 is the loopback ip to connect to a server on the same device/emulator the client is running on.

Comment: Here we have two independ experiments:
1. Emulator + Winwows 10 + IIS
2. Real stb device with local http server.
In both cases request to localhost don't work...

Comment: Of course not. As trying to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 is trying to connect to a server running on the same device/emulator as the client is running on. Every device/emulator is its own localhost to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

`127.0.0.1` is the loopback address for localhost. But when you're inside an android OS, the `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` is android itself and that is not where your server is running.

If you want to connect to the host machine, you need to find out the IP address of your host machine (Windows 10) and use that IP address instead of `127.0.0.1`.

See [How to find your local IP address](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/find-your-ip-address-f21a9bbc-c582-55cd-35e0-73431160a1b9)

However, If you want to refer to the computer which is running the Android emulator, use the IP address `10.0.2.2` instead.

Comment: I have success on emulator + windows case. But what about case:
Local http server on stb + app on stb. This app makes request on stb http server. While I cannot solve my issue for this case...